# React material ui's datagrid: editable column is not working

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

based on this documenation https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/editing/ 
all we need to do to make a cell editable is setting `editable: true` property in the columns defintion like so:

```
const columns: GridColumns = [
  { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 180, editable: true },
  ...
]
```

but for me is not working! even though I'm doing a basic implementation of the `Datagrid` and just want the cell to be editable, very simple cell of type `string` so basically I should get an input text when I double click on the cell, yet it's not working.
is there any thing I should be aware of to make the cell editable?
**This is my code:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridColumns, GridRowsProp } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

export default function BasicEditingGrid() {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
            <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
        </div>
    );
}

const columns: GridColumns = [
    { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 180, editable: true },
    { field: 'age', headerName: 'Age', type: 'number', editable: true },
    {
        field: 'dateCreated',
        headerName: 'Date Created',
        type: 'date',
        width: 180,
        editable: true,
    },
    {
        field: 'lastLogin',
        headerName: 'Last Login',
        type: 'dateTime',
        width: 220,
        editable: true,
    },
];

const rows: GridRowsProp = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Slimen",
        age: 25,
        dateCreated: new Date(),
        lastLogin: new Date(),
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Omar",
        age: 36,
        dateCreated: new Date(),
        lastLogin: new Date(),
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Arbi",
        age: 19,
        dateCreated: new Date(),
        lastLogin: new Date(),
    },
];
```

And I'm simply calling it in the `App` component like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import BasicEditingGrid from "./components/test-editing";

function App() {
  return (
    <BasicEditingGrid/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you put all of your code here (including the `DataGrid` component, and the row data)

Comment: I have even tried the same simple code from the documentation still not working! check my answer I have added the code snippet

Comment: alright after updating the datagrid version it worked, went from `4.0.0-alpha.22` to `4.0.0-alpha.26` did the job but I don't have an answer why !